# combine row and columns in matlab for series

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, series

everyone 
I have problem when make iteration for two variable but, it's combine just in one vector or array

At first i write my input for iteration w(0) as w

> w=[1 50];
>
> for number 1, I use array
>
> e=0:1:(n-1);
>
> f=0:2:(2*n-2); %for 50 in column 2.

I try to use this code

```
w=[1 50];
ww=kron(ones((n),1),w)
e=0:1:(n-1);
f=0:2:(2*n-2);
r=[e',f']
x=ww+r
```

and the output is

```
ww =

 1    50
 1    50
 1    50
 1    50
 1    50
 1    50

r =

 0     0
 1     2
 2     4
 3     6
 4     8
 5    10

x =

 1    50
 2    52
 3    54
 4    56
 5    58
 6    60
```

I want x is output just in one array, in example

```
x =

 1
50
 2
52
 3
54
 4
56
 5
58
 6
60
```

where w=[1 50] can be use difference addition for iteration

Answer (score 2):

Apply this to your `x` matrix:

```
x = reshape(x.',[],1);
```

See [`reshape` doc](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method to create your vector from scratch:

```
x = [1:6;50:2:60];
x(:)
```

Or with your variables:

```
x = [e; f];
x(:)
```